# Working with Javascript dates, getting 0 or above 31

Tags: javascript, date

I am using this code to generate 5 dates for my 'calendar' from the current week:

```
var days = new Array(4);
GetDaysOfWeek(new Date());

function GetDaysOfWeek(date)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
    var $dd = (date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 1 + i);
    var $mm = date.getMonth()+1;
    var $yyyy = date.getFullYear();
if($dd<10){$dd='0'+$dd}if($mm<10){$mm='0'+$mm}
days[i] = $dd+'/'+$mm+'/'+$yyyy;
    }
}
```

However depending what date it is it can return 00/10/2013 or 32/10/2013 on some of my boxes. It seems the only one updating correct is the actual date I am on.

How would I update those 5 dates so I would get the correct dates instead of non exist dates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It'll save lots of headaches.

Comment: What is `$dd` supposed to represent? The day of the month? That calculation does not make sense to me.

Comment: if you want to show next 5 dates after the current use timestamp. 
1. Get the current timestamp (start day): new Date().getTime() / 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
2. then create next day = new Date(current + 24*60*60*1000)
3. then you can show the actual date

Comment: @MattBall Yes $dd means the day of the current week. DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: i wrote wrong formula. the right is:
currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
currentStartDay = currentTimestamp - currentTimestamp%(24*60*60*1000)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat shorter way of creating an array of the dates of 5 weekdays from a given date;

```
function weekdays(d){
  // set date [d] (or today) to the sunday before
  var d = (function(){ 
             this.setDate(this.getDate()-(this.getDay()));
             return this;
           }).apply(d || new Date);
  // create an Array with length 5 and map 5 dates starting
  // from date [d] into it
  return String(Array(5)).split(',')
            .map(function(){
               return new Date(this.setDate(this.getDate()+1));
             }, d);
}
```

It returns the weekdays from the first monday before the date, or, if the given date is a sunday, the dates of the weekdays from the next week.

```
weekdays(); 
//=> [Mon Oct 21 2013 17:14:23 GMT+0200, ... ,Fri Oct 25 2013 17:14:23 GMT+0200] 
weekdays(new Date('2013/10/06'));
//=> [Mon Oct 07 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200, ..., Fri Oct 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200]
```

See also: [**Mozilla DN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on `map`

Maybe [**this jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/jqkyR/embedded/js,html,css,result/) is of use to you?

Answer (score 0):

```
currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime()
currentDay = currentTimestamp-currentTimestamp%(24*60*60*1000)
for (var i = 1; i< 6; i++){
 nextDay = new Date(currentDay + i*24*60*60*1000)
 days[i] = nextDay.toString(); //specify the format yourself
}
```

Comment: This also will give me saterdays and sundays but I only need week days. days[0] has to be monday and days[4] friday.

Comment: it's not clear what do you want. 
you can use date.getDay() to know the week's day and check if it is holiday or not. assume the current day is thursday 24.10.13. So if you want get current week (21-25.10.13) you should do something like the following: specify the current day -> day =date.getDay(), assume day=3; for(var i = 1; i < 6; i++){ previousOrNextDay=new Date(currentDay + (i-day)*24*60*60*1000) etc...